# Сгенерировать URL для https://www.google.com.ua/maps/

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, google-maps-api, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Есть проект в котором используется **Google Maps API** для построения маршрута.

Сейчас задача следующая: внутри web-приложения с помощью **Google Maps API** создать маршрут, после изменить маршрут передвигая маршрут на карте (которая находится в web-приложении) и после сгенерировать ссылку с помощью которой можно открыть гугл карты (https://www.google.com.ua/maps/) где должен отобразиться маршрут с учетом сдвига пользователем в приложении.

Другими словами: через **Google Maps API** сгенерировать ссылку, которая отобразит измененный маршрут в гугл картах

Возможно ли реализовать данную задачу с помощью **Google Maps API**?